# Unique Constraint with multiple null columns

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008, constraint, unique-constraint

I have two tables

`PC(`**Id**`,EmpName Not NULL, PCName NULL, HostName NULL,.... PhysicalLocation NULL, PCType Not NULL)`
`PCNetwork(`**Id**`, EmpName Not NULL, PCName NULL, HostName NULL,IPAddr,....,PhysicalLocation NULL, PCType Not NULL)`

`Id` is a surrogate key, `EmpName` and `PCType` are not null fields and the rest can be null. 
I created Unique Constraint on PC with these columns and FK on PCNetwork. If there is a null in one of the column of a record then the constraint works perfect but if more than one column has null the constraint is not working. This is a follow up question of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797785/database-design-has-a-relationship-with-surrogate-key)

Edit:- My unique constraint and foreign key constriant is not working

`alter table PC add constraint UK_PC_EMPName_PCName_PCType`
`unique (EMPName, PCName, HostName, PhysicalLocation, PCType);`

`alter table PCNetwork add constraint FK_PC_PCNetwork`
`foreign key (EMPName, PCName, HostName, PhysicalLocation, PCType)
references PC (EMPName, PCName, HostName, PhysicalLocation, PCType);`

Comment: That's by design (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166(v=SQL.105).aspx).  What's your question?

Comment: Can you give examples of rows with NULL values that would or would not be considered duplicates? You can create a filtered unique index but the exact definition depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I cannot figure out what your problem is. Can you post your CREATE TABLE statemnts?

Comment: Why do you want a 5-column foreign key? Yikes.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I want PCNetwork common fields to be updated or deleted when PC common fields are updated or deleted, I mean cascade constraints. Like if PC's location changed the Network info of that PC should also have that location. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I still don't understand. Why do you need the same data to exist in *both* tables?

Comment: Oh if I am looking at the Network Info I want to know which IP is assigned to which PC, but since I don't have a natural key for PC table, I am using unique constraint by these fields and why would I need all of them is because I don't want users to go back to PC's table and see where is this PC located or what is its HostName and all. IPAddr is kind of multiattribute field.

Comment: How to add multiple columns with nulls to a constraint or index? Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your database is suffering from a bad data model. You might want to rethink it a little, judging from the tables you've mentioned the model isn't well normalized and you're trying to enforce a foreign key reference to a table column which isn't really a key to anything.
One way to go is something like this :

```
CREATE TABLE EMP (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
                 ,EmpName VARCHAR(100) NULL)

CREATE TABLE PCTypes (id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
                     ,PcTypeName VARCHAR(100) NULL)

CREATE TABLE PC (Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
                ,EmpId INT NULL
                ,PCName VARCHAR(100) NULL
                ,HostName VARCHAR(100) NULL
                ,PhysicalLocation VARCHAR(100) NULL
                ,PCType INT NULL)

ALTER TABLE PC ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PC_EmpId FOREIGN KEY (empId) REFERENCES Emp(id)
ALTER TABLE PC ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PC_PCType FOREIGN KEY (PCType) REFERENCES PCTypes(id)

CREATE TABLE PCNetwork (Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
                       ,NetworkName VARCHAR(100) NULL
                       ,EmpId INT NULL
                       ,PhysicalLocation VARCHAR(100) NULL)

ALTER TABLE PCNetwork ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PCNetwork_EmpId FOREIGN KEY (empId) REFERENCES Emp(id)

CREATE TABLE PCNetwork_PCs (PCNetworkId INT NOT NULL
                           ,PCId INT NOT NULL
                           ,IPAddr NVARCHAR(20) NULL)

ALTER TABLE PCNetwork_PCs ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PCNetwork_PCs_Network FOREIGN KEY (PCNetworkId) REFERENCES PCNetwork(id)
ALTER TABLE PCNetwork_PCs ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PCNetwork_PCs_PC FOREIGN KEY (PCId) REFERENCES PC(id)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq_pcnetworks ON PCNetwork_PCs(PCNetworkId, PCId)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq_pcnetworks_ip ON PCNetwork_PCs(IPAddr)
```

Comment: I didn't do exactly as you said but I changed my db design lil bit, created 2 PC tables of diff pc types, 2 n/w tables corresponding to pc's and still cascading issue didn't get solved because of nulls so I'm doing cascading updates and deletes by queries in pc table triggers which solved my problem. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a unique filtered index. Here is a simpler example, since I don't know what your goal is. We have a baseball team and some players have been assigned numbers; some haven't chosen yet.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PlayerUniforms
(
  PlayerID INT PRIMARY KEY,  -- FOREIGN KEY etc.
  UniformNumber TINYINT NULL -- CHECK (COALESCE(UniformNumber,0) < 100)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX x ON dbo.PlayerUniforms(UniformNumber)
  WHERE UniformNumber IS NOT NULL;
```

Now you can enter multiple `NULL`s in the `UniformNumber` column like ANSI meant it to be, and still enforce uniqueness among the non-`NULL` values.

Comment: I tried unique index as well, it did not work since I had 3 columns with null values. I have updated the question.